# Whenever I am trying to type first letter in my search result it auto removes foucs from the input search box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onchange

I have used Material UI Inputbase to write search query.Whenever I try to press the letter which is the first letter of my search result.It removes focus from my input search box and black border apperars on the whole div containing search box and the results.

I tried to perform simple search operation using Material UI InputBase.Everythig else is working except this issue.

Comment: Please provide some code snippets for our reference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.